# Alternative to Response.Redirect with Request.Querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, response.redirect, request.querystring

I've made a `mvc4` project in `Visual Studio Express 2012 for web`. And there I've made a search function. And a view to show the result.

So normally I would have added this to the `_Layout.cshtml`.

```
if (Request["btn"] == "Search")
{
    searchValue = Request["searchField"];

    if (searchValue.Length > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Views/Search/Result.cshtml?searchCriteria=" + searchValue);
    }
}
```

And that doesn't work. What whould be the alternative to `Response.Redirect` in `mvc4`, which still allows me to keep the searchCriteria to be read with `Request.Querystring` at the `Result.cshtml` page.

Comment: You should actually be doing this in the Controller, not the view.

Comment: You do this through routing and REST behavior. You should be creating a Controller that handles your Search (eg. "SearchController") with your activity being "Result" and you would access the search parameters inside that Controller's Result action. It's very rare that MVC apps directly access the Request object, from what I've seen... it's supposed to be more abstracted than that, and broken up into the proper areas of responsibility, thus the name, "Model/View/Controller"

Comment: [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), The view should not be concerned with routing. It's not it's job.

Comment: Thanks, @Liam, I couldn't remember the proper term! :)

Comment: Dug this one up, in further searching... it gives a little more information on flow-control, as it were, in MVC, in addition to describing what "old school" methods they replace: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/4XDc110313-return-View%28%29-vs-return-RedirectToAction%28%29-vs-return-Redirect%28%29-vs-return-RedirectToRoute%28%29.html

Comment: All in all this entire code block is using the wrong approach. You should never have to use the Request object either. Go back to basics and start again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example would be something like this:

Index.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Search", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("searchCriteria")
    <input type="submit" value='Search' />
}
```

Then the controller:

```
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Results(string searchCriteria)
    {
        var model = // ... filter using searchCriteria

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

`model` could be of type `ResultsViewModel`, which would encase everything you need to display the results.  This way, your search is setup in a RESTful way - meaning it behaves consistently each time.

Answer (score 3):

You should be definetly doing this in your controller, making it return an `ActionResult` and returning a RedirectResult, i.e.:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchCriteria) {
    return Redirect("~/Views/Search/Result.cshtml?searchCriteria="+searchCriteria);
}
```

Btw, I'd also say don't use neither of the Request stuff (or even Redirects), but actions with parameters that MVC will bind automagically from POST or GET parameters. E.g, "www.something.com/search?searchCriteria=hello" will automatically bind the searchCriteria parameter to the Action handling /search. Or, "www.something.com/search/hello" will bind to the parameter defined into your Routing config.

Comment: Again, I think we're missing the point of MVC, here... why would you redirect to yet another controller and action, when you can handle the searchCriteria that you were sent, right in that action?